I need to replace this triac, will you briefly guide me?
This is the component:
G   A
BCR5PM
14L9403
The only that matters is this: BCR5PM?
Any other consideration? Voltage rating? Amps? according to datasheet it supports upto 5 Amps
Last but not least, what does: "14L9403" represent?
Thanks


I think here is the datasheet https://docs.rs-online.com/73a1/0900766b811ae332.pdf

Have you done any research (like googling for BCR5PM or BCR5PM-14L?). Replacements seem to be available everywhere. Datasheets are also easy to find. If you are considering a replacement it would be best to replace it with the same type or one with the same or higher specifications. You have not mentioned anything about its application. BTW, 9403 is a date code (3rd week of 1994, probably).

@StarCat Yes, i forgot to mention that I check on digikey and it says it's obsolete. NOT available, all replacements are a little overkill. BCR5PM-14L says it's: 700V, 5A, 30ma and 2000V isolation. However All I find is: 800v, 6 ~ 15A, 50ma, 2500V isolation, Gate trigger voltage: 1.5v and something about fusing. Those two specs really matter? (trigger voltage and current, as well as fusing)?

@Panamanian Agree that BCR5PM-14L looks to be obsolete. Found an old Renesas Discrete General Catalog Transistor/Diode/Triac/Thyristor from 2007 which lists the BCR5PM-14L(A)  and some other variants. Not sure if that helps with selecting a replacement.

Thank you @StarCat, Liaifat85 and Chester Gillon, it was very useful.

Something like a BTA06-600 should work. What makes you think the triac has failed? It might be more likely the opto driving it.

@Kartman I had no idea how to test it, just ordered two, just in case.
